# Android Listview : Wrap selection from last Item to first Item

Tags: android, listview

Is There anyway we could create a circular navigation with `ListView` when using D-Pad. 
I will explain this further:

- We press Dpad DOWN when we are at last item, First item will be selected.
- If we are in first Item and we press Dpad UP, we go to last Item

Comment: If it doesn't already do this, couldn't you just add a key event listener to the listview, then use modulus on the selected child position?

Comment: Please try my answer, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter method like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

@Override
public MyData getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position % data.size()); // replace data with your ArrayList and MyData with your data type
}
```

Also, in `getView()` method where you get item change

```
MyData d = data.get(position);
```

to

```
MyData d = getItem(position); // Use your data type in place of MyData
```

Now you are all set.

Comment: This is good for doing endless down scrolling. But when you are actually at 0 position and do D-pad UP, this wont wrap it to last item..

Answer (score 0):

A belated late answer, but: just add a key listener that does the wrapping for positions 0 and count-1 only, using the default processing for the other positions. This allows the normal select+scroll to proceed unchanged except for the wrapping cases.

```
listView.setOnKeyListener((View _view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) -> {
        int step = keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP ? -1
                : keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN ? 1
                : 0;
        if (step != 0 && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int count = listView.getCount();
            int pos = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int newPos = pos + step;
            int finalPos = (newPos < 0) ? count-1 : (newPos >= count) ? 0 : -1;
            if (finalPos >= 0) {
                // use default scrolled movement unless we actually need to wrap.
                listView.post(() -> listView.setSelection(finalPos));
                return true; // consume event
            }
        }
        return false;
});
```